# How to create confidence Interval plot in R

Tags: r, plot, regression, confidence-interval

## b

```
DF1 = read.csv("Nerlove.3.csv",header=TRUE)

head(DF1, n=5)

split = round(nrow(DF1) * 0.60)


train = (DF1[1:split, ])

test = (DF1[(split + 1):nrow(DF1), ])

model = lm(output ~ ., train)

summary(model)

plot(train$cost, train$output, ylab = "Output", xlab = "Cost",main = "....")


abline(model, col=2)
```

## c

```
plot(test$cost, test$output, ylab = "Output", xlab = "Cost",main = "....")

model1 = lm(output ~ ., test)

abline(model, col=2)

prediction = predict(model, test)

plot(prediction, main = "....")

abline(model1, col=2)

summary(model1)
```

## d

```
library(stats)

X_0 = data.frame(cost = test$cost)

FI_mean = predict(model, newdata = X_0, interval="confidence", level = 0.95)

FI_ind =  predict(model,newdata = X_0, interval = "prediction")

plot(test$cost, test$output, ylab = "Output", xlab = "Cost",main = "....")

abline(model, col=2)

min = test$cost

max = test$cost

newx = seq(min,max)

matlines(newx, FI_mean[,2:3], col = "blue", lty=2)
```

**I need to plot the Confidence interval result I found around the regression line, but I'm getting an error. can anybody please help me to fix this. Thanks**
[**This is the link for my data. I have edited it and only using the cost and output data in my dataframe**](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/csv/Ecdat/Nerlove.csv)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it wrong because you are using all the variables while developing the linear model by the command `model = lm(output ~ ., train)`. But during plotting, you are using cost vs. output plotting (as in case of b and c) and in case of d, you are trying to predict using only one variable i.e. cost. Regression plot should be made between observed output vs. predicted output. For that, you can use the following code

```r
library(lattice)
library(mosaic)
#> Loading required package: dplyr
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
#> Loading required package: ggformula
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
#> Loading required package: ggstance
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'ggstance'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:ggplot2':
#> 
#>     geom_errorbarh, GeomErrorbarh
#> 
#> New to ggformula?  Try the tutorials: 
#>  learnr::run_tutorial("introduction", package = "ggformula")
#>  learnr::run_tutorial("refining", package = "ggformula")
#> Loading required package: mosaicData
#> Loading required package: Matrix
#> Registered S3 method overwritten by 'mosaic':
#>   method                           from   
#>   fortify.SpatialPolygonsDataFrame ggplot2
#> 
#> The 'mosaic' package masks several functions from core packages in order to add 
#> additional features.  The original behavior of these functions should not be affected by this.
#> 
#> Note: If you use the Matrix package, be sure to load it BEFORE loading mosaic.
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'mosaic'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:Matrix':
#> 
#>     mean
#> The following object is masked from 'package:ggplot2':
#> 
#>     stat
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:dplyr':
#> 
#>     count, do, tally
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     binom.test, cor, cor.test, cov, fivenum, IQR, median, prop.test,
#>     quantile, sd, t.test, var
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     max, mean, min, prod, range, sample, sum
DF1 = read.csv("Nerlove.csv",header=TRUE)

head(DF1, n=5)
#>    cost output   pl     sl  pk     sk   pf     sf
#> 1 0.082      2 2.09 0.3164 183 0.4521 17.9 0.2315
#> 2 0.661      3 2.05 0.2073 174 0.6676 35.1 0.1251
#> 3 0.990      4 2.05 0.2349 171 0.5799 35.1 0.1852
#> 4 0.315      4 1.83 0.1152 166 0.7857 32.2 0.0990
#> 5 0.197      5 2.12 0.2300 233 0.3841 28.6 0.3859

split = round(nrow(DF1) * 0.60)

train = (DF1[1:split, ])

test = (DF1[(split + 1):nrow(DF1), ])

model = lm(output ~ ., train)

summary(model)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = output ~ ., data = train)
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
#> -409.65 -112.20   -4.61   94.20  430.76 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#> (Intercept)  1182.296   1861.876   0.635    0.527    
#> cost          146.231      6.127  23.866  < 2e-16 ***
#> pl             14.897     80.142   0.186    0.853    
#> sl          -2471.312   1930.034  -1.280    0.204    
#> pk              1.477      1.011   1.460    0.148    
#> sk           -869.468   1874.585  -0.464    0.644    
#> pf            -13.701      2.365  -5.794 1.08e-07 ***
#> sf           -947.958   1861.490  -0.509    0.612    
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 169.3 on 87 degrees of freedom
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.9111, Adjusted R-squared:  0.904 
#> F-statistic: 127.4 on 7 and 87 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

#Calibration plotting
pred_cal <- predict(model, newdata=train)
df_cal <- data.frame(Observed=train$output, Predicted=pred_cal)

xyplot(Predicted ~ Observed, data = df_cal, pch = 19,  panel=panel.lmbands,
       band.lty = c(conf =2, pred = 1))
```

[image]

```r
#Validation plottig
pred_val <- predict(model, newdata=test)
df_val <- data.frame(Observed=test$output, Predicted=pred_val)

xyplot(Predicted ~ Observed, data = df_val, pch = 19,  panel=panel.lmbands,
       band.lty = c(conf =2, pred = 1))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-01-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and answer. It's really helpful. But as I mentioned, I have edited the data and in my dataset, there are only two-column, cost and output. I have removed the other variables as I needed only one observed variable and one predicted variable for my work. In that case...form my code what  I should have done to fix that? your answer is perfect, I am just curious to know. Thanks again.